# Ubuntu keeps on rebooting after enabling TPM 2.0 from BIOS (APTIO utility)

Tags: 18.04, bios, tpm

I am having Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed on to my system. I wanted to implement TPM functionalities. I enabled TPM 2.0 from Trusted Computing option in the BIOS. After this when I rebooted my system, the OS didn't start. Rather it keeps on rebooting after the American Megatrends screen comes.

The system is stuck in this loop until I disable TPM from the BIOS again.

Really want help to solve this issue.

Comment: You are missing a key part: where, when and how did you enable tpm2 in the installed Ubuntu? "I enabled TPM 2.0 from Trusted Computing option in the BIOS" is only a minute part of what you need to do. https://github.com/tpm2-software/  and https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools are good read regarding tpm 2

Comment: als see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#TPM

Comment: See I am very new to TPM but I have learnt somewhere that we have to first turn on the TPM from the bios. Only then the hardware will be available for use from the OS. Have I got it wrong? @Rinzwind

Comment: You need to approach this bottom 1st: Ubuntu kernel needs to have TPM enabled before you turn on TPM. You a least need a storage root key. Without it the OS is not allowed to boot. But... if that is new to you I would suggest keeping TPM disabled.

Comment: Do you have any sort of material that I can refer to set the SRK. I know in theory the operations of TPM. But now I am getting down to implementing the EK, SRK , Owning , etc practically. Any help to get me started is much appreciated. Thanks in advance. @Rinzwind